# What does "Win Button" + "Print Screen" do on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, print-screen

Today I was going to System Properties with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> and accidentally pressed <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>. By doing this, Windows 8 RTM x86 lowered the display brightness for 2 seconds and then returned to normal.

I checked that the printscreen was copied to clipboard by pasting it on Paint, but I didn't notice any difference from a normal printscreen (by pressing only <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> button). I also checked that Windows 7 doesn't have the same behavior.

So, is this just a new "animation" for the printscreen process on Windows 8, or does it actually have a functional difference from the traditional method?

Comment: Not mentioned on this chart: http://windowsteamblog.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-53-48-metablogapi/4667.Keyboard_2D00_shortcuts_2D00_for_2D00_Windows_2D00_8_5F00_5756566F.png

Comment: [Evidence](https://superuser.com/questions/494155/what-is-the-shortcut-for-taking-screenshots-on-windows-8/494165#494165) for Win + PrtSc ***both*** changing the clipboard and saving to the 'Pictures/Screenshots' folder.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It takes *and* saves the screenshot. It places the saved screenshot into your pictures folder as a PNG.

For reference: [Windows 8: Capture Screenshots (en-US)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12081.windows-8-capture-screenshots-en-us.aspx)

Comment: Lol, I didn't know about that. It already worked on Windows 7?

Comment: @Diogo: Doesn't seem like this existed in Windows 7.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I just checked on my Windows-7 machine and didn't noticed any change on my picture images... I would like to find a reference for this feature on some Windows 8 doc...

Comment: @Diogo: Nothing official, but http://www.itworld.com/software/258746/take-screenshots-windows-8 http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2012/04/windows-8-guide-how-to-take-screenshots/ http://blog.laptopmag.com/how-to-take-a-screenshot-in-windows-8 Everybody but us knows ;D

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Heh, it's a very nice feature... Now we don't need "Paint" anymore :D

Comment: @Diogo you will need the paint at all when you need to edit the shot :D

Comment: any way to take screenshot of only the focused window and not the whole screen and save it automatically?

Comment: @Moab I do not think there is as of now.

Comment: found some of the new kbrd shorcuts for W8 here...http://www.pcworld.com/article/251022/windows_8_consumer_preview_keyboard_shortcuts.html

Comment: @Moab I don't have 8 to try it but have you tried `Win` + `Alt` + `PrintScr`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yep that was the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 3):

As Ben and user142485 point out, <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> takes a screenshot, dims the screen to let you know something happened, and saves a .png file to your pictures. This is an enhanced version of the screenshot functionality that has been in Windows going back to at least Windows 95. It might have even been in Microsoft Bob or Me, but thank goodness I never had the chance to find out. Good-bye Paint, or Gimp, or whatever else you used to paste the screen shot into before saving.

Curiously, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>, which has also been around for just as long, continues to behave the way it did in previous versions of Windows. It captures a screen shot of the active window. However, the screen doesn't dim, and the screen shot is NOT saved to your pictures, so you'll need to continue to use Paint in this scenario.

Comment: I'm not sure if my keyboard doesn't support the simultaneous presses of `Alt`+`Win`+`Print Screen` or if windows doesn't support it. But that combination would be **very** useful!

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answer; I suppose it lowers the brightness to let you know a screen shot just occurred, just like on an iPhone, or when a photo is captured from Photo Booth on a MacBook.