# Can I use the snipping tool to take a screenshot of the windows 8 start screen or modern apps?

Tags: windows-8, screenshot

One of the tools I've found invaluable in answering questions on SU is the [snipping tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipping_Tool). I may on occasion need to take screenshots of part of the start screen or 'modern' apps. I may not want to take a complete screenshot, and while I can use <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> and switch back into desktop to paste it, this is clunky if I need to document a multi-step process.

Can I use the [snipping tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipping_Tool) on modern apps or the start screen? If not is there a configurable way to save a series of screenshots to a fixed folder, say when I press a combination of keys, so I can work, screenshot, then crop and annotate the folder of images?

Comment: What do you mean by snipping tool?

Comment: @soandos it's a screenshot utility that started shipping with Windows 7 (or Vista?).

Comment: @soandos - Under Windows 7, Click start > Accessories > Snipping tool. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipping_Tool for more info. Louis - Windows Vista.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering the last part of your question, as per [this question](https://superuser.com/a/463960/85165) pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> will save screenshots to your `Pictures` folder.

Comment: What if you have a mac and you don't have a PrintScreen button?

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot. I have even tried putting Windows 8 UI apps on a second extended monitor, but the tool just can't see the apps.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do take a screen shot is using the Steps Recorder App. It opens on the Desktop, after which you could start "recording" - Open the start screen and any app you wish to take a screen shot off. Simply right click (you can see a red dot near your mouse pointer confirming the screenshot).

After you are done you could stop recording and go back to the desktop mode. You will see a sequence of screenshots and you could select which ever you want.