# Snipping tool in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, snipping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use the snipping tool to take a screenshot of the windows 8 start screen or modern apps?](https://superuser.com/questions/491016/can-i-use-the-snipping-tool-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-windows-8-start-screen-o)

When I open an application, say IE, in Windows 8, it occupies the full screen.

Now, if I want to take a snip of it using Snipping tool, the application closes.

Any idea how I can take a screen shot of the application?

Answer (score 5):

Traditional screenshot methods will not work for Modern UI apps.

To take a screenshot of a Modern UI app, press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>.
This will save a screenshot to `My Pictures\Screenshots`.  (it works on the desktop too)

You can then open the image in any non-Modern image viewer and use the Snipping Tool there.

Comment: That works fine, but i want "Snipping Tool", which takes selected screenshot cuts to work

Comment: @DivakarRaj: That won't work.  Sorry.

Comment: Edit the screenshot using mspaint after using Win+printscreen.