# Clipboard usage

Tags: windows, clipboard, screenshot

I am just curious with the Windows clipboard. I use printscreen to capture a screenshot. Then I use the same command to capture another screenshot.

How exactly do I access the previous screenshots? Is that overwritten with the new one?

Comment: Windows 8 adds a new [Win+PrtScr feature](http://superuser.com/questions/463957/what-does-win-button-print-screen-do-on-windows-8) that auto-saves.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A program called Snapshoter will help you achieve this:

http://www.xabierpayet.com/

Snapshoter is a portable screen capture tool which offers all the essential screen capture features with an option to save them in unlimited screenshot stack. It provides the utility of saving as many screenshots as you want in a list which can be pasted with either a simple drag and drop or by using default Paste hotkey combination; Ctrl + V.

A review entitled **"Snapshoter Is Screenshot Clipboard Manager And Editor"** for Addictive Tips was written by Usman Javaid  on May 13, 2011 explaining the application in more detail:

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/snapshoter-is-screenshot-clipboard-manager-and-editor/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the old screenshot is overwritten when creating the second screenshot. Use the snipping tool instead. Here you can save the picture.